# ATX Power Supply Switch - What is the actual name of this switch?

Tags: atx

Initially I was wondering if anyone makes a cover that attaches to these, or if they come in a style other than the little stepped up squares, but don't know what to search for, everywhere just seems to call the switch an 'atx power supply switch'. Do they have a specific name beyond that?

[image: atx power supply switch]

Comment: I think it's called just 'power switch' or 'motherboard power switch'. I don't think there is any other special name for that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think they are part of the ATX spec, so it depends on the PC case itself whether it uses these buttons or not.  But I believe they are simply called 8x8 buttons as they are 8mm square (but check your case first as there are 7x7 and 6x6 ones too!)

They are available in latching and non-latching versions.  The non-latching ones (only switched on when being pressed) are used for power and reset, and the latching ones (press on, press off) used to be used in early cases for the legacy turbo button.

Here's a photo lifted from an Aliexpress seller for their 8x8 button listing:

[image: A number of identical 8x8 buttons arranged haphazardly]

Some early ATX cases used an AT style switch, but changed from latching to non latching.  The AT switch has part number KDC-A04-2S and looks like this:

[image: Four KDC-A04-2S push buttons]

I don't have a part number handy for the non-latching variant used in ATX cases, however these switches seem to be available with two different sized spade connectors (the large one shown above, and a smaller one that fits the ATX to AT power supply adapters found online), so be sure to buy the right one if needed in your application.

Comment: Looks like 8x8 might be as useful of an answer as I'm going to get. It blows my mind that something so standard doesn't have a standard name with standard accessories available. You gave me enough info to find them on Aliexpress and apparently they often use PS-22F03 as a part number and that can be used to also locate little caps for the switches.